# How to change "add to basket" button text in WooCommerce based on product category?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've created CPT with my events and for each event I've created individual product in WooCommerce. Now I'm using this shortcode in my code

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="'.get_field('event_ticket').'" show_price = "FALSE"]'); ?>
```

for displaying "add to basket" button placed on each event. Every event have Product Category "event" and now I want change default text on "add to basket" button, but only for those products which have 'event' Product Category.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi Damian, questions regarding WooCommerce are off-topic here...

Comment: I have seen many posts about WooCommerce here so I let myself to write...

Comment: they’re getting closed, but not quick enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to filter the text.  here's the function from core WC that builds that text.  In both of these instances `$this` will be the product.

```
/**
 * Get the add to cart button text for the single page.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
public function single_add_to_cart_text() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', $this->get_button_text() ? $this->get_button_text() : _x( 'Buy product', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ), $this );
}

/**
 * Get the add to cart button text.
 *
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
public function add_to_cart_text() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', $this->get_button_text() ? $this->get_button_text() : _x( 'Buy product', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ), $this );
}
```

So you're going to want to add a filter to either `woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text` or `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` that checks if `$this` is an event and changes the text if it is or returns the default text if it isn't.